# Construction of irrational number for which inequality got rational numbers

Tags: calculus, inequality, real-numbers

Basically, we have to construct an irrational number α for which the following is true:

∀n ∈ N, ∃p/q ∈ Q such that

$$|α - p/q | ≤ 1/q^n$$

Why can't we just always say $q = 1$ and from that, it would be pretty easy?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: well, that would be easy.  if $\alpha = \sqrt 2$ then for any $n$ we have $|\sqrt 2 -1| < 1= \frac 1{1^n}$.  We can only assume the person who asked the question meant $\frac pq \not\in \mathbb Z$.  (and *probably*, but it might not matter, that $p,q$ are in lowest terms.)

Comment: For the problem as you've stated it here, you are altogether correct, letting $q=1$ does the trick. But it's likely that the problem meant to ask for there to be *infinitely many* rational number $p/q$ with the property $|\alpha-p/q|\le1/q^n$ no matter how large $n$ is taken to be, not just for the existence of a single example of such a $p/q$.

Comment: Today I got the info that it was a silly task...so thank you all for your replies!